# Mask sensitive text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

I have an element `<a href="#" class="masked_text">123456789</a>`.

Can I show the number as stars even though the actual number is preserved? The number can be changed with javascript, so it wont help to use

```
$('.masked_text').text('*************');
```

I don't know if it is possible to show something without changing the content. I don't want an image placed above the element or something like that, so I'm really out of guesses :-)

Comment: can I ask what would be the purpose of changing digits to stars if the digits still appear in the code?, that might help reach the best solution

Comment: I use x-editable, so the user should still be able to edit the number. A better approach would probably be to make a custom input which uses <input type="password">, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: I'm still not clear on what type of behavior you're looking for.. do you want the stars to appear as the user is typing in numbers, basically just like typing a password?

Comment: It could do it, but I the problem is not the input field itself. The issue is when the text is saved and is visible at the page. So I really just want to show a different text than what is actually in the element. I hope it's clear :-)

Comment: Ok, so, you are saving a number that was entered, then you display it on screen as stars (no page reload or something..), but want access still to the numbers on the client (javascript).. correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could set in CSS class font to symbols. That way text would become unreadable, unfortunately numbers would remain.

```
   .maskedText {
        font-family: Symbol;
    }
```

Comment: hhh so that's useless since he wants it for numbers ;]

Answer (score 0):

Just save the number in a variable and replace it with * like so:

```
var theNumber;
function inputFieldSubmitCallback() {
    theNumber = $(".masked_text").text();
    $(".masked_text").html(theNumber.replace(/\d/g, "*").show();
}
```

** you can instead of course store the number in localStorage or a js object... but it's still in the client (not secure.. if that's an issue).